# How to merge multiple datasets in long format with missing data in SPSS

Tags: syntax, merge, spss

I am working on a project compiling data from a longitdinal study with approx 300 participants. The data I have been supplied with is divided into multiple SPSS-files, which all are in "long-format". Each data set contain the longitudinal information for one test. The participants have been measured at 20 time-points, so there is a maximum of 20 observations per participant.

I am to compile all these data sets into one SPSS-file in wide-format.

However, there are multiple challenges when combining these data sets into one data set:

- Missing visits are not represented by a row in any of the dataset.
- The response rate (i.e. total number of rows) differ between measure.
- There are multiple errors in coding of visits (i.e. the "timpeoint" variable is wrong in many of the cases), but i have date of each visit.

To correct for two of these challanges have manually checked in one the databases, and corrected errorous "timepoint"-values, added missing rows. This "mother-database" is now of sound quality.

I was wondering if there is a way to merge the rest of the spss-files with this one, while meeting the following criteria:

- Match by ID number.
- Match by visit-date, using "mother-database" as a definition of a visit (note that not all visits are available in the data sets i am trying to merge with the "mother-database").
- In case of missing data on a visit, add missing values.
- In case of missing visit (i.e. no date), add missing values.

Comment: do you have a correct visit number for each visit? or do the same dates correspond to the same visit numbers in all participants (these can be recoded into visit numbers)?. If so, you can use `add files` to get all your data in long format, and then use `casestovars /id=id /index=visitnum/ ...` to get it all into wide format - this will also take care of all the missing visits - you'll just get missing values.

Comment: Yes, in the "mother-file" i have the correct number of vists for each participant (20 visits). But the number is not correct in the other files. 

If i add the files as is now, there wil be a mismatch i rows between the correct data (in the mother-database) and the new data added.

Edit: read you post again. I have the correct visit-number in the "mother-database", but there are many errors in the other databases.

Comment: if you match the files you will end up with a file with 20 lines and the original variables X the number or participants (requiring renames for all the original variables) - is this what you want? I was suggesting not to `match` the files (side by side) but to `add` them (pile them on top of each-other), so you'll end up with just the original variables and 20 lines for each participant

Comment: In the current mother'dataset I have all cases at all timepoints. The problem is the data I am adding, where i have all cases, but not all timepoints. 

I have previously used the 'STAR JOIN' command to merge datasets, which won't work in this case.

Comment: if you're sure you want to match the files try `match files` instead of `star join`.